# correct way to generate next employee code in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sequence

Requirement is to start  employee code from LMT000001 and my developer is using below query to get next employee code and inserting when employee registers it. is this correct way ?

```
SELECT CONCAT('LMT',MAX(maxCoulmn)+1) AS maxnum FROM (
        SELECT  MAX(SUBSTRING(employee_code, 4)) as maxCoulmn FROM employee_register WHERE
        1 AND employee_code REGEXP '^LMT[0-9]*$'
      ) AS employee
```

Comment: No. Use an auto_increment `id` column and `SELECT CONCAT('LMT', LPAD(id, 6, '0') AS employee_code`

Comment: *is this correct way ?* It can be correct only when server operates in "single mode" - i.e. when concurrent connections which may execute shown code are physically impossible.

Comment: The correct way would be to abandon the requirement. Remember; sql is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else. This appears to be an application level code problem. Also, what is a 'Coulmn'?

Answer (score 0):

I would do that way:

1. First the column employee code should be unique and NULL by default.
2. After the insert, you can define the employee code with the ID generated by the auto increment as follow:

```sql
UPDATE employee
SET code = CONCAT('LMT', LPAD(id, 6, '0')
WHERE id = :id
AND code IS NULL
```